# Why is the absorption coefficient (α) not zero for energy of incident photon less than the band gap of the semiconductor?

Tags: semiconductors, solid-state-devices

α ( Absorption Coefficient) tells us about the absorption of a photon by a semiconductor for the creation of electron-hole pairs.

[image: alpha vs lambda graph]

The absorption coefficient increases abnormally as the energy of photons crosses the bandgap, which is expected as the photons are able to provide the energy for excitation of electrons from the valence band to the conduction band. 
But, when the energy of Photons is less than the bandgap energy, why is the value of absorption coefficient not zero?

How can there be any absorption of a photon when its energy is not sufficient to cause excitation of an electron?

Comment: Where did that graph come from?

Comment: It's from solid state electronic devices book. https://www.amazon.in/Solid-State-Electronic-Devices-Streetman/dp/9332555087